# CSS transition on padding-bottom sized box act weird

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to animate a box sized with padding-bottom in a horizontal list of the same boxes.

The animation consist in changing it's proportion (making it wider) and it's general size (making it bigger than the others). The problem is that when the animation starts it moves the other boxes vertically and in the end it restores the vertical positioning.

I'm using also the margin to move it up (since it's bigger) and avoid it to get space in the bottom part. Briefly I use margin to keep the height the same.

I noticed that the problem comes from padding-bottom, even if in the beggining I thought it was the margin part.

**This is the main css:**

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: width ease-in-out 150ms;
}
.item:hover {
  width: 28%;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 166%;
  background: violet;
  transition:
    padding ease-in-out 150ms,
    margin ease-in-out 150ms
  ;
}
.item:hover::after {
  padding-bottom: 130%;
  margin: -8.4% 0; /* this avoids to occupy space vertically */
}
```

Here is what I'm trying to do and another type of animation with the same problem but without making the box bigger, so the problem it's clearly the `padding-bottom` property.

```css
.container,
.container1 {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10% 0;
  margin: -10% 0;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: width ease-in-out 150ms;
}

.item:hover {
  width: 28%;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 166%;
  background: violet;
  transition: padding ease-in-out 150ms, margin ease-in-out 150ms;
}

.container .item:hover::after {
  padding-bottom: 130%;
  margin: -8.4% 0;
}

.container1 .item:hover::after {
  padding-bottom: 116.495%;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 100px 0 20px">
  Here the effect should be like scale, but occupying space horizontally
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div style="padding: 100px 0 20px">
  Here the effect should be like animating the width only, keeping the same height
</div>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution!

Simply I used `vertical-align: middle` and a larger negative `margin`.
In this way, during the animation, the non-synchronized transition won't be noticeable due to the automatic vertical alignment.

It works for both the shown examples, even if it is more noticeable in the latter.

```css
.container,
.container1 {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10% 0;
  margin: -10% 0;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: width ease-in-out 150ms;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item:hover {
  width: 28%;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 166%;
  background: violet;
  transition: padding ease-in-out 150ms, margin ease-in-out 150ms;
}

.container .item:hover::after {
  padding-bottom: 130%;
  margin: -20% 0;
}

.container1 .item:hover::after {
  padding-bottom: 115%;
  margin: -20% 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 100px 0 20px">
  Here the effect should be like scale, but occupying space horizontally
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div style="padding: 100px 0 20px">
  Here the effect should be like animating the width only, keeping the same height
</div>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `flexbox` would be a good idea. I have created a fiddle for you.

Thanks me later.

```css
.container, .container1 {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10% 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: width ease-in-out 150ms;
}
.item:hover {
  width: 28%;
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 166px;
  background: violet;
  transition:
    padding ease-in-out 150ms,
    margin ease-in-out 150ms
  ;
}
.container .item:hover::after {
  padding-bottom: 188px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I need to keep the proportions and I need also the box to "exit" the container vertically

Answer (score 0):

I Hope It's Help You :)

```css
.container, .container1 {
    font-size: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.item::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 166%;
  background: violet;
  transition:
    padding ease-in-out 150ms,
    margin ease-in-out 150ms
  ;
}
.container1 .item:hover {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: 100px 0 20px">
  Here the effect should be like scale, but occupying space horizontally
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div style="padding: 100px 0 20px">
  Here the effect should be like animating the width only, keeping the same height
</div>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, I need to keep the same spacing between the boxes, so I can't use `transform`...